# Adding an instance to a MEF container

Tags: c#, silverlight, mef

How can you add an already created instance to a MEF container/cataloge to use when resolving Imports. I want the functionality that Unity gives with the `RegisterInstance` method on its containers.

Comment: MEF is not an IoC container, you shouldn't expect from MEF that it will replace Unity as it is not made for it. You can read about it: http://www.google.pl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mef+as+ioc

Comment: @A. I do not expect that it will replace Unity, but so far the project came along without including another IoC framework and this is the only thing that I need and does not justify adding another framework if it is possible to resolve this requirement with MEF.

Comment: MEF2 is a full fledged IOC.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [ComposeExportedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986608.aspx) function for this, like so:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer();
container.ComposeExportedValue<Application>("Application", Application.Current);
```

Comment: And if I want to register it with a name also?

Comment: The other overload for ComposeExportedValue takes a string for the contractName. Updated my example.

Comment: anyone know how to do this in System.Composition? (The PCL version).